# In AndEngine, how do I drag around an object that will fall when not being touched?

Tags: android, andengine, physics

I'm new to AndEngine and having a little trouble. I want to drag a sprite around the screen and when the finger is lifted from the sprite, have the object fall to the bottom of the screen. Every time the screen is touched (but not a sprite) have a new sprite created at that point. I tried to combine the PhysicsExample which creates shapes every time you touch and then makes them fall and the TouchDragExample that lets you drag a sprite around the screen. What I am left with is a sprite being created where the last sprite was and immediately being moved to where the screen was touched. Each sprite then has its own "gravitational field" or something. They don't fall, but position themselves as far from one another as possible. Also, when creating my texture region, I'm left with the image at the point (0,0). How do I load the image to the texture region, but not have it display to the screen? My code follows:

```
public class TestGFXActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener, IOnSceneTouchListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Camera camera;
    private static final int Camera_Width = 512;
    private static final int Camera_Height = 512;
    int centerX, centerY;


    private BitmapTextureAtlas backgroundTextureAtlas;
    private ITextureRegion backgroundTextureRegion, circleTR;
    private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
    private Scene scene;
    private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = new Camera(0,0,Camera_Width,Camera_Height);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);

        return engineOptions;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        backgroundTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),
                512,512,TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        backgroundTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(backgroundTextureAtlas, this, "bluelavabackground2.png",0,0);
        circleTR = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(backgroundTextureAtlas, this, "bubble2.png",0,0);
        backgroundTextureAtlas.load();
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        centerX = (int) ((Camera_Width - this.backgroundTextureRegion.getWidth())/2);
        centerY = (int) ((Camera_Height - this.backgroundTextureRegion.getHeight())/2);

        scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.setOnSceneTouchListener((IOnSceneTouchListener) this);
        scene.setBackground(new Background(1,1,1));
        this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH), false); //Sets x and y acceleration 

        final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
        final Rectangle ground = new Rectangle(0, Camera_Height - 2, Camera_Width, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, Camera_Height, 2, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, Camera_Height, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        final Rectangle right = new Rectangle(Camera_Height - 2, 0, 2, Camera_Width, vertexBufferObjectManager);

        final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
        PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);

        this.scene.attachChild(ground);
        this.scene.attachChild(roof);
        this.scene.attachChild(left);
        this.scene.attachChild(right);

        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);




        final Sprite background = new Sprite(centerX,centerY,this.backgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(background);
        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        final Sprite face;
        final Body body;
        if(this.mPhysicsWorld != null) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                face = new Sprite(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), this.circleTR, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

                face.setScale((float) .25);
                scene.attachChild(face);
                scene.registerTouchArea(face);
                scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
                this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face, body, true, true));
                return true;
            }else if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){
                scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        final Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
        this.mPhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);
    }

    public void onResumeGame() {
        super.onResumeGame();

        this.enableAccelerationSensor(this);
    }

    public void onPauseGame() {
        super.onPauseGame();

        this.disableAccelerationSensor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to register touch area using `onClick(not in onSceneTouchEvent)`. To do this just implement `onClickLisener`. To make your Sprite fall you may easily use PhysicsBox(just set the gravity). Or, optionally, you may create PhysicsHandler and set velocities.